# local variables arent working Xna when assigned

Tags: variables, timer, xna, local

Im needing to use local variables but when i use them for a timer (decreases time until conditions are met) it doesnt work

```
   for (int i = 0; i < Weapons.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Weapons[i].ItemType == 6)
            {
                if (standard.IsKeyDown(Keys.G))
                {
                    Cannons.Add(new CannonFire(this));
                }
            }
            else if (Weapons[i].ItemType == 7)
            {
                float Recharge  = Weapons[i].Laser.Rate;
                Recharge -= (float)gametime.ElapsedGameTime.Seconds;
                if (standard.IsKeyDown(Keys.G) && Recharge < 0)
                {
                    laser.Add(new LaserFire(this, new Vector3(Weapons[i].Laser.range, 1, 1) ));
                    Recharge = Weapons[i].Laser.Rate;
                }
            }
        }
```

other relevant code is where im getting the rate from

```
   public class LaserItem
{
    float Damage;
    float Range;
    float Last;
    float RechargeRate;
    public float damage
    {
        get { return Damage; }
        set { Damage = value; }
    }
    public float Rate
    {
        get { return RechargeRate; }
        set { RechargeRate = value; }
    }
    public float Life
    {
        get { return Last; }
        set { Last = value; }
    }
```

it works without the timer but i cant have it like that because i dont want 300 lasers to be built every time someone hits the key. as far as i can tell the timer is set to the laser rate every frame so it never reaches 0 (this section it in the update function)

for this piece of code its fine but when i need it in a loop  i have to use local variables;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out, XNA has a TimeSpan thing you can use its easier to work with and you can tell it if it reaches a number reset and do what you want

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand, what you are doing in the code is that you're creating a new local variable with the value set to the recharge rate of the laser every single update, firing it when the time from the last update is longer than the recharge rate - this would occur only on a very slow update.

Taking into account the automatic Update (the main loop one) calling of XNA, what would help you is setting some class variable for the Weapon, e.g. `RemainingRecharge` and when you fire, set it to the recharge rate and substract the elapsed time every update until it reaches zero or less. The only difference from your code is that the recharge is moved to the class instance and thus preserved between updates.

Comment: I think i grasp what you mean by putting it as a class variable instead of a local one, which i would normally do but i cant because as you see in this part Weapons[i] <<it is a list, ill update you with the full code segment its just the for loop as the whole file ... has a few hundred lines easy.  but the point is i have to make a list of timers but i cant do that because id have the same problem i have to assign a timer with Weapons[i].Laser.Rate<< to the laser  because of different kinds of weapons.  and it would have to be assigned in the update function... so the same thing would happen

Comment: I'm not sure what seems to be the problem here, to be honest.
With the timing, another option I see, slightly easier on checking, is to put LastFired field instead of RemainingRecharge into the class, and when you try to fire, check if LastFired + RechargeRate is less than the current time. But all the suggestions suppose that you can edit the classes.

Answer (score 0):

`Recharge` isn't a reference or a pointer; it's a copy (as `float` and `double` are immutable types). So, assigning a value to `Recharge` at the end of the `if()` block does absolutely nothing. (I'd bet that it even gets removed by the compiler).

Try this:

```
       else if (Weapons[i].ItemType == 7)
                {
                    float recharge  = Weapons[i].Laser.Rate;
                    recharge -= (float)gametime.ElapsedGameTime.Seconds;

                    if (standard.IsKeyDown(Keys.G) && recharge < 0)
                    {
                        laser.Add(new LaserFire(this, new Vector3(Weapons[i].Laser.range, 1,1)));

                        /// changed the the next line:                        
                        Weapons[i].Laster.Rate = recharge;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: @user2112726 We're going to need more details than "it doesn't work."  Are weapon and laser structs or classes?

Comment: The weapon[] < is a list  that contains a list of classes which is called items  which in itself contains classes of each kind of item ... the one we are concerned with is called LaserItem in that class the relevant code is 
             
float RechargeRate;
public float Rate
        {
            get { return RechargeRate; }
            set { RechargeRate = value; }
        }